# Java Queue for Scheduler

Tags: java

I am wondering how would I implement a queue of schedules?

For example, I have a ScheduledExecutorService that would perform a task every 30 seconds until success. Sometimes this task would succeed in 30 seconds, sometimes it would take a few minutes. ScheduledExecutorService would be given a job periodically. I would like it so that ScheduledExecutorService would move onto the next job only if its current job is successful. How would I implement this?

Comment: So you want single-thread execution?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, a single-thread execution.

Comment: So you just want to execute a `Queue<Runnable>` sequentially? One after another?

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation, you can use `scheduleAtFixedDelay` to impose a delay between execution:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay
>   between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the
>   next.

Not exactly how you worded your question, but it looks like its what you are trying to do.

See more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: The method will execute a given task at a given delay. But OP wants to have a JobQueue containing many different jobs and then work through it sequentially.

Comment: You can have a job queue and run the next at fixed delay while the queue is not empty. The doubt I had was whether the scheduler should be kept busy while the queue is not empty, or if a 30s pause between jobs of 5min duration was acceptable.